# Stuttering screens on 14.04 on MacPro

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, ati, xorg

A friend gave me an old MacPro and installed 14.04 on it. Having a problem with occasional stutters on the video - screen freezes for a second or two, then returns to normal. Guessing it's something to do with XOrg, any suggestions how to troubleshoot?

Running both AMD and Nvidia display cards using the XOrg open source drivers:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]     Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770] [1002:68b8] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Apple Inc. MacPro5,1 [Mac Pro 2.8GHz DDR3] [106b:00cf]
Physical Slot: 1
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 58
Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
Memory at b3e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at b3e20000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: radeon

06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210]   [10de:0a65] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34d5]
Physical Slot: 3
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
Memory at b2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at b3000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

System:
9.8 GiB RAM
Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5462 @ 2.80GHz × 8 
Gallium 0.4 on AMD JUNIPER
64-bit

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my nvidia driver on my computer when I installed Ubuntu.

Boot ubuntu and run just the terminal so that the display card doesn't have to do much. Alternatively you can press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to open the full terminal.

Now, what you want to do is uninstall the nvidia drivers using

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Now, install packages. To do this you need to install the packages for your kernel, which can be found through typing

```
uname -r
```

This will display your kernel, eg. -3.3.3-33-generic.

Now enter "sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers"
With **your** kernel at the end, e.g

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers-3.3.3-33-generic
```

Now, there's a ppa for a great team that release much more stable repo's. Install using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates&&sudo apt-get update
```

Install their drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Now you need to check if it has installed correctly (14.04 doesn't seem to do this well)

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

If nothing happens, you need to manually install through

```
sudo depmod -a
```

the load it

```
sudo modprobe nvidia_current
```

Now you can restart through

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps