# Really slow Video on 14.04 with a nvidia GeForce4 420 Go 32m

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 in Dual Boot with Windows XP.
Every thing works great on my HP TC1100 with Intel Pentium(R) M Processor 1.20GHZ,
2.0G RAM, 32-bit. But the video is really slow. I went to nvidia's website and
found: NVIDIA-Linux-x86-96.43.23-pkg1.run . But I don't know how to install it,
or even if I should install it. Or should I run a different version of Ubuntu?

I tried Turtle Bum's answer three times. and it crashed the GUI interface each
time. I can bring up a command line, but any GUI I try to run I just get a blank
screen.

Comment: Couple of points:   1) determine your graphics card first with `sudo lshw -c display` and look for `product:` line to make sure you have nvidia, and if nvidia - which model. 2) you can go to the [nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and get the correct packages . 3) `*.run` files work the same as shell scripts. Make it executable with `chmod 755 filename.run` and run with `./filename.run`.

Comment: I have an old HP  tower , which was left to me by my friend, and it also has Intel Pentium M processor. The GUI is also slow. My workaround so far is to use `openbox` or `blackbox` desktop environments, which are very minimalistic. My suspicion is that CPU is just slow, it's single core. Or perhaps this particular chipset doesn't play with Ubuntu well. Go figure, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered how to uninstall and update the nvidia drivers here: [Stuttering screens on 14.04 on MacPro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511065/stuttering-screens-on-14-04-on-macpro/511082#511082)

It uninstalls the nvidia driver(s) and then installs a more stable version through a repository. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nVidia stopped supporting this GPU after the 3.2.x kernel in Linux.

Nvidia is not a very open source-friendly company, so since they won't open source their drivers and won't continue development for older products, that means the only support that exists for older cards is the Nouveau drivers, which are the reverse-engineered community built open source drivers.

Those don't support the GPU for any acceleration, which is why it's so slow. Unless someone figures out how to reverse-engineer the 420 further, this is what we're stuck with now.